# Jenkins Fontconfig head is null even after installing fontconfig

Tags: rhel, jenkins

I am trying to install generic Jenkins with jenkins.war. Getting following error while starting.

```
2024-03-05 15:23:36.018+0000 [id=1]     SEVERE  hudson.util.BootFailure#publish: Failed to initialize Jenkins
java.lang.RuntimeException: Fontconfig head is null, check your fonts or fonts configuration
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.getVersion(FontConfiguration.java:1263)
```

I have installed fontconfig

```
rpm -qa | grep fontconfig
fontconfig-2.8.0-5.el6.x86_64
fontconfig-devel-2.8.0-5.el6.x86_64
```

I also tried starting with -Djava.awt.headless=true

I am on

- openjdk 21
- Jenkins 2.440.1
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.10 (Santiago)
- base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch